# Delete column based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to identify several criteria in a range within a Google Sheet. Upon identifying the value, the script should return me the column where the value is found and then call a function to delete the columns. Below is the code I've put together but I'm running into issues.

I get an out of bounds error during deleting.

```
//Delete Column
function deleteColumn(col) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var numCol = sheet.getRange("A1:T23").getNumColumns();
  var data = sheet.deleteColumn(col);

  for (var i = numCol; i >= 0; i--) {
    var remove = data;
    Logger.log(remove + " was removed");
  }  
}

//find columns
function findColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:T23");
  var values = data.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {   
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] == "Notes" || values[i][j] == "Billable" || values[i][j] == "Total") {
        var col = j+1;
        Logger.log("columns numbers found" + col);
        deleteColumn(col);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Part of my thinking which I'm not quite catching, is when the columns begin to delete. This effectively changes the number of the column, so I'm attempting to start at the number of columns and work back (right to left).

Comment: I suspect it may be due to the fact that you are attempting to change the range during the process... that is... you set a static range A1:T23. Once you delete the first column perhaps this range does not exist (but have not tried this myself)? Try using a dynamically set range.

Comment: I originally tried a dynamic range using sheet.getDataRange(); but still was hitting the same issue, along with another for identifying the columns multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out of bounds error is because of your looping range here:

```
(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
```

The `values` array is 0-based, meaning it indexes from `0..values.length-1`.

Some of your statements are mixing up object types. Always double-check this.

```
  var data = sheet.deleteColumn(col);
```

You'll see that [`deleteColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumn(Integer)) returns a `Sheet` - the same sheet you already had. This is done for *chaining*, allowing you to perform multiple actions on a Sheet in one statement. Your variable names imply you expected to receive a copy of the deleted column, and your `log()` call tries to display it... you likely saw `[object]` in the log because of that.

You're right to count down when eliminating rows or columns. It appears you didn't do it in all the right places.
The calling function, `findColumn()` has increasing loops (which will get out-of-sync as colums are deleted), while the called function, `deleteColumn()`, has a decreasing loop (which it probably doesn't need at all). Why does `deleteColumn()` exist, anyway? If it did what it looks like you intended, it would delete all your data.

Last, since you're deleting columns, you should loop over columns with your outer loop. The inner loop, over rows, can be `continue`d (exited) if the condition for column deletion is met. Do you mean to have the inner loop? It looks for those three values in every row. If you meant only to look in the Headers, that's row 1 (index 0 in the array).

```
function deleteNBTColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:T23");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:T23");
  var values = data.getValues();
  var numRows = values.length;
  var numCols = values[0].length;

  for (var col = numCols-1; col > 0; col--) {   // count down over columns   
    for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {   // count up over rows
      switch (values[row][col]) {               // examine cell contents
        case "Notes":
        case "Billable":
        case "Total":                           // in these cases...
          sheet.deleteColumn(col+1);            // delete column in sheet (1-based)
          continue;                             // continue with next column
          break;                                // can't get here, but good practice
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: deleteColumn() was suppose to delete right to left, but you were correct it deleted almost all columns, but the error would pop.  Great explanation and comments.  Made a world of difference in understanding the logic.